# Unable to change default download directory for chrome selenium instance (Linux/Ubuntu)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have a webdriver running with the following configs:

```
  options.add_argument("--kiosk-printing")
  options.add_argument("--print-to-pdf")

  prefs = {
            "download.default_directory": download_path,
            "download.prompt_for_download": False,
            "download.directory_upgrade": True,
            "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
            "safebrowsing.enabled": False}
  options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
```

I set the download_path to an existing directory. When the browser runs I even open the chrome://settings/downloads page to check the path and it does indeed show that my default download directory is the one I set. However when I try to save anything the prompt does not point to that folder, instead pointing to the default downloads directory.

The kicker is if I manually change the download directory in the chrome instance it does work, even though I'm setting it to the exact same folder that it was saying it was pointing to.

Am I doing something wrong? Not sure why it says that the directory is set but not actually doing it even though it's reflected in the Chrome settings.

EDIT: Possible solution that worked for me. I rummaged through my chrome settings file and found the preferences file that holds all your settings.

For some reason, `download.default_directory` only affects the visual representation of your download path. When you manually change the download directory, it adds another object to your settings dict `savefile.default_directory` with the exact same information. But this one actually affects where the download is stored.

I don’t know why or what the heck is up with this, but it seems to work.

Comment: that usually means the path is wrong or the permissions on the directory are preventing Chrome from writing there.  Btw, you should only need to set "download.default_directory".  Chrome doesn't prompt by default.

Comment: @pcalkins My path is correct, I’m 100% certain because in the manual settings page it shows the exact same path whether I set it manually or automatically. Only in the case where I set it manually does saving actually save to the location. I don’t know about permission errors though. 

However I have found that it works if I add the parameter to my prefs dict: “savefile.default_directory”: directory. I’ll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution, I don’t know if this affects something else that I’m not aware of. However it looks like the prefs dict should look something like this.

```
prefs = {
   "download.default_directory": download_path,
   "savefile.default_directory": download_path
}

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
```

Looks like at some point, or at least for my browser, the download directory SAYS it’s whatever you set the downloads.default_directory to, but the actual place it saves to is where you set the savefile.default_directory to. Very weird and undocumented behavior as far as I’m aware but… just hope this helps someone else as I’ve been wracking my brain for literal days to figure this out.