# Selenium 4.14 - ChromeDriver - default download directory not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot set a default download directory for my driver.

My code is the following:

```
    def setup_method(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        options = Options()
        prefs = {'download.default_directory': r"C:\Test",
                 'download.prompt_for_download': True,
                 'download.directory_upgrade': True,
                 'safebrowsing.enabled': True
                 }
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Still when I download somehting it goes to Downloads folder.
It was working before when I was using local webdriver but since Selenium has implemented the driver manager, I dont use service argument.

Could you please help what am I missing?

[**SOLUTION HERE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176954/22775020**]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change default download directory for chrome selenium instance (Linux/Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175638/unable-to-change-default-download-directory-for-chrome-selenium-instance-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION HERE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176954/22775020

...'savefile.default_directory': self.download_directory... should be added

Answer (score 0):

This way you convert the absolute path into a relative path

```
import os

def __init__(self):
    time.sleep(1)
    full_download_path = r"absolute/path/to"

    self.path = os.path.join(base_path, full_download_path)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : self.path, 
             "credentials_enable_service": False,
             "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
```

Comment: I also tried:
```script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  
download_directory = os.path.join(script_directory, "Test_Downloads")  
...  
prefs = {'download.default_directory': self.download_directory,  
...  ```
It is not working unfortunately... I think the issue is not with the path.

Comment: for some reason it works if I don't use propt for download. If I set it false it downloads the file to the correct directory, but I want to use prompt in order to rename the file I'm downloading

Comment: I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176954/22775020